# Convertion from hexa decimal value to String

Tags: java, android

In my program i am getting a string in hexa format. i want to convert that to string. How to do it ?

Thanks and Regards.
Parvathi

Comment: convert a string to a string? do you mean to an int?

Comment: please edit your question and add an example: (1) a string that you get (hex format) and (2) a string that shows the expected result after conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to convert hexadecimal into string

```
String hexadecimalnumber = "00000011";
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(hexadecimalnumber);
    String requiredString = big.toString(16);
    System.out.println("...data..."+requiredString);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: "00000011" looks suspiciously like a string representation of an 8-bit binary representing 3 (decimal). Or is it meant to be a 32-bit hex string representing 17 (decimal). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
String hex = "ff";
hex = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Test 
{
    private static int hextoint(char c) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            return c - '0';
        }
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
            return c - 'a' + 10;
        }
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
            return c - 'A' + 10;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private static String hexdec(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        if(len % 2 != 0){
            return null;
        }
        byte[] buf = new byte[len/2];
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            char c1 = str.charAt(i);
            char c2 = str.charAt(i + 1);
            int b = (hextoint(c1) << 4) + hextoint(c2);
            buf[size++] = (byte)b;
        }

        return new String(buf, 0, size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str = "616263";
        String out = hexdec(str);
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea to write your own when this functionality already exists in the Java libraries ( see:http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int%29 ) - and this code won't correctly work with negative hex numbers

Comment: hi, parseInt is NOT hexdec. if you decode a hex string by split into 2 bytes length strings and then parseInt, it's much SLOW.